# How to get rid of "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater"

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

This question is very similar to a lot of questions related with the warning `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater/less/etc`

However, I couldn't find a solution for my particular problem, and I think there should be one.

So, I have a `numpy.ndarray` similar to this one:

```
array([[ nan,   1.,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       ..., 
       [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
```

I want to calculate `array > 0.5`, which gives exactly the result I want, but with the warning for being comparing with `nan`:

```
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
Out[68]: 
array([[False,  True, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       ..., 
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

I basically want to calculate `array > 0.5`, but without the warning showing up.

My restrictions:

- I do **NOT** want to just suppress the warning with `with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):`
- I need to maintain the original array, thus I cannot change it.

I have come up with a simple solution:

- Change the `nan` in the original matrix (`array[np.isnan(array)] = -np.inf`), recovering it back after I do my comparison (`array[array == -np.inf] = np.nan`)

But I think it is just a waste of time all these calculations when (I think) it should exist a direct way to do this at once. I have been exploring the `numpy.ma` module and the `numpy.where` function, but I couldn't find this "direct" solution which I want.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Make your comparison function (value != nan) and (value > 0.5)

Comment: @AlexvonBrandenfels Your solution doesn't work. First, I have to change `nan` to `numpy.nan`. But even after that I have an error: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: "I do NOT want to just suppress the warning" - why not?

Comment: @user2357112 Because I don't think that's correct. I'm making a comparison in a 3-valued logic, thus actually the result of comparing NaN with something else might be false or other value. In a future release of numpy this result could change thus I wanted to make sure I would always have an expected result

Comment: "In a future release of numpy this result could change" - that is extremely unlikely to happen, and if it did, you'd have to rethink all your NaN handling anyway.

Comment: Yes, that's truth. However, it was just an example. Looking to the problem as it is now, the expected result is entirely dependent on how numpy sees NaNs. With the solution Divakar gave me, the expected result is always the same, whether I use numpy or other framework As you also say, with this solution I will never ever need to rethink NaN in other situations

Comment: Well, I can say that my reason is just "I wanted to make this in a correct way, not dependent on how a 3rd party software handles NaNs"

Comment: @tjiagoM sorry, I meant for my comment to be interpreted as pseudocode, but it ended up being valid python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would have that warning whenever an array containing at least one NaN is compared. The solution would be to use `masking` to compare only the non-NaN elements and we would try to have a generic solution to cover all types of comparisons with the help of [`comparison based NumPy ufuncs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/ufuncs.html#comparison-functions), as shown below -

```
def compare_nan_array(func, a, thresh):
    out = ~np.isnan(a)
    out[out] = func(a[out] , thresh)
    return out
```

The idea being :

- Get the mask of non-NaNs.
- Use that to get the non-NaN values from input array. Then perform the required comparison (greater than, greater than equal to, etc.) to get another mask, which represents the compared mask output for the masked places.
- Use this to refine the mask of non-NaNs and this is the final output.

Sample run -

```
In [41]: np.random.seed(0)

In [42]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(4,5)).astype(float)

In [43]: a.ravel()[np.random.choice(a.size, 16, replace=0)] = np.nan

In [44]: a
Out[44]: 
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,   4.,   7.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,   1.,  nan],
       [ nan,   7.,  nan,  nan,  nan]])

In [45]: a > 5  # Shows warning with the usual comparison
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
Out[45]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

# With suggested masking based method
In [46]: compare_nan_array(np.greater, a, 5)
Out[46]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Let's test out the generic behavior by testing for `lesser than 5` -

```
In [47]: a < 5
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
Out[47]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [48]: compare_nan_array(np.less, a, 5)
Out[48]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Damn! The solution is actually SO simple. I have been following all your edits eheh Thank you so much, that's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: But the readability is reduced. What about setting this to be the default way?

Comment: This is not what I call "making the warning go away". It's carefully avoiding operations which raise this warning. And it has overhead both in the code and in the runtime. However, short of hacking NumPy's source code, you can actually do `np.seterr(invalid='ignore')`.

Comment: @TomaszGandor OP has already tried that and doesn't want to do so. It's under `My restrictions:` section in the question.

Comment: Solution can also be applied to `np.sign()` when you're are trying to get the sign from an array with `nan` values. Error would be `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sign`. Instead of `df['b'] = np.sign(df['a'])`, you can use `dfS['b'] = evaluate_nan_array(np.sign, df['a'])` where `def evaluate_nan_array(func, a): out = ~np.isnan(a)     out[out] = func(a[out])     return out`

Answer (score 7):

There is a better way - you don't want to suppress the warning forever, because it could help you find other mistakes later on.

Following the suggestions found in this question: [RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861891/runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-divide)

## The Right Way:

If the result is the one you want, you can just write:

```
with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
    result = (array > 0.5)

# ... use result, and your warnings are not suppressed.
```

## A different Wrong Way:

Otherwise, you could meet your restrictions by copying the array:

```
to_compare = array.copy()
to_compare[np.isnan(to_compare)] = 0.5  # you don't need -np.inf, anything <= 0.5 is OK
result = (to_compare > 0.5)
```

And you don't need to "recover" the NaNs in your array.