# Backpropagation computes NaN values if training set size is big

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, nan

I am developing a shallow fully connected ANN from scratch which learns thanks to the Gradient Descent with momentum algorithm. This is the code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import expit, xlog1py

def softmax(y):
    e_y = np.exp(y - np.max(y))
    return e_y / e_y.sum()

def cross_entropy(y, t, derivative=False, post_process=True):
    if post_process:
        if derivative:
            return y - t
        return -np.sum(np.sum(xlog1py(t, softmax(y)), axis=0))

def sigmoid(a, derivative=False):
    f_a = expit(-a)
    df_a = np.multiply(f_a, (1 - f_a))  # element-wise
    if derivative:
        return df_a
    return f_a


def identity(a, derivative=False):
    f_a = a
    df_a = np.ones(np.shape(a))
    if derivative:
        return df_a
    return f_a


def generate_data(n_items, n_features, n_classes):
    X = np.asmatrix(np.random.normal(size=(n_items, n_features)))
    targets = np.asarray(np.random.randint(n_classes, size=n_items))
    targets = one_hot(targets)
    return X, targets


def one_hot(targets):
    return np.asmatrix(np.eye(np.max(targets) + 1)[targets]).T


class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self):
        self.layers = []

    def add_layer(self, layer):
        self.layers.append(layer)

    def build(self):
        for i, layer in enumerate(self.layers):
            if i == 0:
                layer.type = "input"
            else:
                layer.type = "output" if i == len(self.layers) - 1 else "hidden"
                layer.configure(self.layers[i - 1].neurons)

    def fit(self, X, targets):
        MAX_EPOCHS = 200
        epoch_loss = []

        # batch mode
        for epoch in range(MAX_EPOCHS):
            predictions = self.predict(X)
            self.back_prop(targets, cross_entropy)
            self.learning_rule(l_rate=0.01, momentum=0.01)
            loss = cross_entropy(predictions, targets)
            epoch_loss.append(loss)
            print("E(%d) on TrS is:" % epoch, loss)


    # Columns of predictions  
    def predict(self, dataset):
        z = dataset.T 
        for layer in self.layers:
            z = layer.forward_prop_step(z)
        return z

    def back_prop(self, target, loss):
        for i, layer in enumerate(self.layers[:0:-1]):
            next_layer = self.layers[-i]
            prev_layer = self.layers[-i - 2]  
            layer.back_prop_step(next_layer, prev_layer, target, loss)

    def learning_rule(self, l_rate, momentum):
        # Momentum GD
        for layer in [layer for layer in self.layers if layer.type != "input"]:
            layer.update_weights(l_rate, momentum)
            layer.update_bias(l_rate, momentum)


class Layer:

    def __init__(self, neurons, type=None, activation=None):
        self.dE_dW = 0  
        self.dE_db = 0
        self.dEn_db = None  
        self.dEn_dW = None  
        self.dact_a = None  
        self.out = None
        self.weights = None  
        self.bias = None
        self.w_sum = None  
        self.neurons = neurons  
        self.type = type  
        self.activation = activation  
        self.deltas = None

    def configure(self, prev_layer_neurons):
        self.weights = np.asmatrix(np.random.normal(-1, 1, (self.neurons, prev_layer_neurons)))
        self.bias = np.asmatrix(np.random.normal(-1, 1, self.neurons)).T  # vettore colonna
        if self.activation is None:
            # th approx universale
            if self.type == "hidden":
                self.activation = sigmoid
            elif self.type == "output":
                self.activation = identity

    def forward_prop_step(self, z):
        if self.type == "input":
            self.out = z
        else:
            self.w_sum = np.dot(self.weights, z) + self.bias
            self.out = self.activation(self.w_sum)
        return self.out

    def back_prop_step(self, next_layer, prev_layer, target, local_loss):
        if self.type == "output":
            self.dact_a = self.activation(self.w_sum, derivative=True)
            self.deltas = np.multiply(self.dact_a,
                                      local_loss(self.out, target, derivative=True))  # (c,batch_size)
        else:
            self.dact_a = self.activation(self.w_sum, derivative=True)  # (m,batch_size)
            debug = np.dot(next_layer.weights.T, next_layer.deltas)  # <<<< problem here
            self.deltas = np.multiply(self.dact_a, debug)

        self.dEn_dW = self.deltas * prev_layer.out.T

        self.dEn_db = self.deltas

        self.dE_dW = self.dEn_dW

        self.dE_db = self.dEn_db  

    def update_weights(self, l_rate, momentum):
        # Momentum GD
        self.weights = self.weights - l_rate * self.dE_dW
        self.weights = -l_rate * self.dE_dW + momentum * self.weights

    def update_bias(self, l_rate, momentum):
        # Momentum GD
        self.bias = self.bias - l_rate * self.dE_db
        self.bias = -l_rate * self.dE_db + momentum * self.bias


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Dog: 0 -> 000
    # Cat: 1 -> 010
    # Mouse: 2 -> 001
    net = NeuralNetwork()
    d = 4  # (n_features)
    c = 3  # classes
    n_items = 10  # increasing this gives NaN in EBP formula, in debug variable

    for m in (d, 4, c):
        layer = Layer(m)  
        net.add_layer(layer)

    net.build()

    X, targets = generate_data(n_items=n_items, n_features=d, n_classes=c)

    net.fit(X, targets)
```

If `n_items` value is low, such as 10 or 100, the learning works properly:

```
E(0) on TrS is: -0.27547576455869305
E(1) on TrS is: -0.33774479466660445
E(2) on TrS is: -0.3295771015279694
...
E(199) on TrS is: -0.33026951829371987
```

Unfortunately when `n_items` gets bigger, such as 1000 I get this error:

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
> self.deltas = np.multiply(self.dact_a, debug)

and:

```
E(0) on TrS is: -0.3337489007828587
E(1) on TrS is: -0.01614463421285259
E(2) on TrS is: -0.33594156066981384
E(3) on TrS is: -0.11378512597000995
E(4) on TrS is: -0.33508867936192843
E(5) on TrS is: -0.33276323614435077
E(6) on TrS is: -0.33310949105565746
E(7) on TrS is: -0.224661060748479
E(8) on TrS is: -0.3321560115270673
E(9) on TrS is: -0.22289014654421438
...
E(138) on TrS is: nan
E(139) on TrS is: nan
E(140) on TrS is: nan
E(141) on TrS is: nan
...
E(199) on TrS is: nan
```

I think this is caused by `debug` variable which grows until it reaches the `sys.float_info.max` value which is `1.7976931348623157e+308`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861891/runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-divide)?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis the problem might be referred to debug variable increasing with epochs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have exploding gradients. Maybe try some regularisation.

A couple of general things though. Your weight initialisation is going to give very large starting values which can lead to exploding gradients in itself.

[image: Distribution of random weight initialisation.]

Instead, consider something more like:

> np.random.normal(-0.1,0.02,...

This example doesn't affect the weights, but it is also worth looking at the logic of some of your methods. For instance, sigmoid always calculates the derivative whether it is used or not. Perhaps instead use two methods (one job per method) or at least calculate the derivative inside the if:

```
def sigmoid(a, derivative=False):
f_a = expit(-a)
if derivative:
    df_a = np.multiply(f_a, (1 - f_a))  # element-wise
    return df_a
return f_a
```

For more about exploding gradients and weights initialisation, see this https://medium.com/usf-msds/deep-learning-best-practices-1-weight-initialization-14e5c0295b94 .

Comment: I think "Exploding gradient" is the key